# MySQL поиск по таблице по двум столбцам с выборкой

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос, поиск

Прошу помоь составь запрос в MySQL.
Пользователи имеют номер региона area_code и ищут вид деятельность name_business.
Как правильно составить запрос, чтобы он отбирал вид деятельность только для региона, который имеет пользователь?
пока есть такая конструкция, но она не отрабатывает полностью:

```sql
SELECT * FROM patentactivity WHERE name_business LIKE '%кожи%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM patentactivity WHERE area_code LIKE '%77%'
ORDER BY area_code LIKE '%77%';
```

Надо, чтобы запрос Изготовление изделий из кожи был только для 77 региона.

Скриншот таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Where and - оба условия соберите вместе

Comment: @splash58 Спасибо большое. Работает.